# Enable/Disable MSCONFIG Startup Items with C#

Tags: c#

```
RegistryKey HCU = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        foreach (string Programs in HCU.GetValueNames())
        {
            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Item Name"] = Programs;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        RegistryKey HLM = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        foreach (string Programs in HLM.GetValueNames())
        {

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Item Name"] = Programs;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\DEV2\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup");
        FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*");
        foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
        {
            if ((fi.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row["Item Name"] = fi.Name;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

        }


        RegistryKey HKLM = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupreg", true);
        foreach (string Programs in HKLM.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            // string GetFilePath = HKCU.GetValue(Programs).ToString();

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Item Name"] = Programs;
           // row["Location"] = "HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupreg";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        RegistryKey HKLM2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupfolder", true);
        foreach (string Programs in HKLM2.GetSubKeyNames())
        {

            RegistryKey productKey = HKLM2.OpenSubKey(Programs);
            if (productKey != null)
            {
                foreach (string value in productKey.GetValueNames())
                {
                    if (value == "item")
                    {
                        row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["Item Name"] = Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("item"));
                        // row["Location"] = "HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupreg";
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        uxDgvStartupItems.DataSource = dt;

        DataGridViewColumn column = uxDgvStartupItems.Columns["Item Name"];
        column.Width = 600;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow ro in uxDgvStartupItems.Rows)
        {

                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell ch1 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)ro.Cells[0];
                ch1.Value = true;

        }


        RegistryKey HKCU3 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupfolder", true);
        foreach (string Programs in HKCU3.GetSubKeyNames())
        {

               RegistryKey productKey = HKLM2.OpenSubKey(Programs);
               if (productKey != null)
               {
                   foreach (string value in productKey.GetValueNames())
                   {
                       if (value == "item")
                       {
                           string txt = Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("item"));

                           foreach (DataGridViewRow ro in uxDgvStartupItems.Rows)
                           {
                               string txt1 = ro.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                               if (txt == txt1)
                               {
                                   var ch2 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) ro.Cells[0];
                                   ch2.Value = false;
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
        }


        RegistryKey HKCU1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupreg", true);
        foreach (string Programs in HKCU1.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            string txt = Programs;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow ro in uxDgvStartupItems.Rows)
            {
                string txt1 = ro.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                //var txt1 = uxDgvStartupItems.Rows[uxDgvStartupItems.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
                if (txt == txt1)
                {
                    var ch2 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)ro.Cells[0];
                    ch2.Value = false;
                }
            }
        }
        HKCU1.Close();
```

Comment: I want to know how to Enable or Disable Window Startup Items with c#.
Anyone some ideas about it????/  Please give answer. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be better to place your comment at the top of your post using the `edit` functionality - that way, people can see what you're looking to do before showing your current code.

Comment: @nickhar : Sorry, actually the above code is used to display startup items, Now i want to enable/disable startup items form c# window form, just like MSCONFIG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to Enable or Disable MSconfig startup items with C# window application

```
private void uxSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{
string username = Environment.UserName;
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to change startup of Item(s)?", "Confirm Startup", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (j%2 == 0)
                        list1.Add(list[j]);

                }

               foreach (DataGridViewRow ro in uxDgvStartupItems.Rows)
                {
                    var cellname = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell) ro.Cells[1];
                    string x = Convert.ToString(cellname.Value);
                    foreach (string i in list1)
                    {
                       if (i == x)
                        {
                            string name = i;
                            var sourcee = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)ro.Cells[2];
                            string source = Convert.ToString(sourcee.Value);
                            var CbxCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)ro.Cells[0];

                            if ((bool)CbxCell.Value == true)
                            {
                                int flag = 0;
                                string itemname = "";
                                RegistryKey HKLM2 =
                                    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupreg",
                                                                     true);
                                foreach (string Programs in HKLM2.GetSubKeyNames())
                                {

                                    RegistryKey productKey = HKLM2.OpenSubKey(Programs);
                                    if (productKey != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (string value in productKey.GetValueNames())
                                        {
                                            if (value == "item")
                                            {
                                                string txt = Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("item"));

                                                if (txt == name)
                                                {
                                                    itemname = Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("command"));
                                                    HKLM2.DeleteSubKey(name, false);
                                                    flag = 1;

                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


                                RegistryKey HKLM4 =
                                    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
                                        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupfolder", true);
                                foreach (string Programs in HKLM4.GetSubKeyNames())
                                {

                                    RegistryKey productKey = HKLM4.OpenSubKey(Programs);
                                    if (productKey != null)
                                    {
                                        foreach (string value in productKey.GetValueNames())
                                        {
                                            if (value == "item")
                                            {
                                                string txt = Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("item"));

                                                if (txt == name)
                                                {
                                                    HKLM4.DeleteSubKey(Programs, false);
                                                    flag = 2;
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


                                if (flag == 1)
                                {
                                    RegistryKey startupKey =
                                        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
                                    startupKey.SetValue(name, itemname);
                                    startupKey.Close();
                                }

                                if (flag == 2)
                                {
                                    string path = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup";
                                    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(targetPath);
                                    FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*");
                                    foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
                                    {
                                        string itemName = fi.Name;
                                        itemName = itemName.Substring(0, itemName.LastIndexOf('.'));

                                        if (itemName == name)
                                        {

                                            string sourceFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, name + ".lnk");
                                            string destFile = Path.Combine(path, name + ".lnk");

                                            File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
                                            fi.Delete();

                                            fi.Delete();

                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                if (source == "registry")
                                {
                                    int flag = 0;
                                    string path = "";
                                    RegistryKey startupKey =
                                        Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
                                                                         true);
                                    foreach (string Programs in startupKey.GetValueNames())
                                    {
                                        if (Programs == name)
                                        {
                                            path = Convert.ToString(startupKey.GetValue(name));
                                            startupKey.DeleteValue(name, false);
                                            startupKey.Close();
                                            flag = 1;
                                        }

                                    }

                                    if (flag == 0)
                                    {
                                        RegistryKey startupKey1 =
                                            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                                                "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
                                        foreach (string Programs in startupKey1.GetValueNames())
                                        {
                                            if (Programs == name)
                                            {
                                                path = Convert.ToString(startupKey1.GetValue(name));
                                                startupKey1.DeleteValue(name, false);
                                                startupKey1.Close();
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }

                                    RegistryKey HKCU =
                                        Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
                                            "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupreg", true);
                                    RegistryKey HKCU1 = HKCU.CreateSubKey(name);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("command", path);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("hkey", "HKLM");
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("inimapping", "0");
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("item", name);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("key", "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("DAY", DateTime.Now.Day);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("MONTH", DateTime.Now.Month);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("YEAR", DateTime.Now.Year);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("HOUR", DateTime.Now.Hour);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("MINUTE", DateTime.Now.Minute);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("SECOND", DateTime.Now.Second);
                                }

                                if (source == "folder")
                                {
                                    string path = "C:^Users^" + username + "^AppData^Roaming^Microsoft^Windows^Start Menu^Programs^Startup";
                                    string path1 = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup";

                                    DirectoryInfo di =
                                        new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup");
                                    FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*");
                                    foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
                                    {
                                        string itemName = fi.Name;
                                      itemName = itemName.Substring(0, itemName.LastIndexOf('.'));

                                        if (itemName == name)
                                        {
                                            string sourceFile = Path.Combine(path1, name + ".lnk");
                                            string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, name + ".lnk");

                                            File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
                                            fi.Delete();

                                        }

                                    }

                                    RegistryKey HKCU =
                                        Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
                                            "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupfolder", true);
                                    RegistryKey HKCU1 = HKCU.CreateSubKey(path + "^" + name);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("path", path1 + "\\" + name);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("location", path1);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("item", name);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("command", path1);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("backupExtension", ".Startup");
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("backup", "C:\\Windows\\pss\\" + name + ".Startup");
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("DAY", DateTime.Now.Day);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("MONTH", DateTime.Now.Month);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("YEAR", DateTime.Now.Year);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("HOUR", DateTime.Now.Hour);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("MINUTE", DateTime.Now.Minute);
                                    HKCU1.SetValue("SECOND", DateTime.Now.Second);

                                }

                            }

                          }

                    }
                }


                if (
                    MessageBox.Show("Do you want to restart system to save these changes", "Confirm Restart",
                                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    bool privilege;
                    WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                    WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
                    privilege = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
                    if (privilege == true)
                    {
                        Process.Start("ShutDown", "/r");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You have not sufficient privileges to restart computer");
                    }
                }

                 list.Clear();
                list1.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void uxDgvStartupItems_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //string[] list = new string[100];
            string name = Convert.ToString(uxDgvStartupItems.Rows[uxDgvStartupItems.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].FormattedValue);
            list.Add(name);

        }
```